# Why a List<SuperClass> Object can be casted to a Subclass Object?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have found that, the case 1 and case 3 can be compiled without errors, but case 2. (SubClassB extends SuperClassA, which is abstract class)
What I wonder is, why case 1 and case 3 have no compile errors. 
If it is a JDK bug, why case 2 can't pass the cast check?

```
// case 1        
List<SuperClassA> a = new ArrayList<>();
SubClassB b = (SubClassB) a; 

// case 2
List<Number> m = new ArrayList<>();
Long n = (Long) m; //Error:(xx,yy) java: incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Number> cannot be converted to java.lang.Long

// case 3
List<Exception> e = new ArrayList<>();
RuntimeException d = (RuntimeException) e;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that case 1 and case 3 will both fail at runtime.

At compile time, the compiler will complain about incompatible casts only if the language spec says so. The language spec allows cases 1 and 3 because they will not 100% fail.

Case 1 will not 100% fail , as far as the compiler is concerned, because it thinks that `a` can contain an instance of any type that implements `List<SuperClassA>`. What if there is a subclass of `SubclassB` that actually implements `List<SuperClassA>`? And what if `a` actually contains an instance of that subclass of `SubclassB`? Then the cast would succeed!

Same thing goes for case 2. What if there is a subclass of `RuntimeException` that actually implements `List<Exception>`? And what if `e` actually contains an instance of that subclass of `RuntimeException`? Then the cast would succeed!

Case 2 shows an error because `Long` is `final`. There *couldn't* be a subclass that implements `List<Number>`, so it will definitely fail.

This is specified in [§5.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1) of the spec (italics are the relevant bits):

> Given a compile-time reference type S (source) and a compile-time reference type T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if no compile-time errors occur due to the following rules.
>
> ...
>
> If S is an interface type:
>
> - If T is an array type, then S must be the type `java.io.Serializable` or `Cloneable` (the only interfaces implemented
>     by arrays), or a compile-time error occurs.
> - If T is a class or interface type that is not `final` (§8.1.1), then if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that
>     both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types, and that the
>     erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> *Otherwise, the cast is always legal at compile time (because even if T
>   does not implement S, a subclass of T might).*
>
> - *If T is a class type that is final*, then:
>
>   – If S is not a parameterized type or a raw type, then T must implement S, or a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: "the compiler will complain about incompatible casts only if it is 100% sure that the cast will fail." Not quite: `(Integer) (String) null` won't compile, but it wouldn't fail either (as demonstrated by `(Integer) (Object) (String) null`).

Answer (score 6):

In the case of unsafe casts, you get a warning as the compiler can't work out whether this cast should be allowed or not. (It was allowed without warning in older Java versions so hard to remove now)

Note: `Long` is a `final` class and it assumes there is no way there is a sub-class of `Long` where this cast could work.

You can create a class like

```
class MyException extends RuntimeException implements List<Exception> {
```

so these are valid lines of code

```
List<Exception> e = new MyException();
RuntimeException d = (RuntimeException) e; // ok.
```

Comment: Cool, thank you for your help. (I've corrected my question words, it's compile error not exception)